# wordpress admin menu. naming of sub menus

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how one would add a custom top level admin menu with a handful of submenus without having the top level one repeat itself in the submenus.
This is what i want:

```
Posts
    All Posts
    Create
    etc.
```

Click on posts and get to the "all posts" page. All I'm getting is:

```
MyPostType
    MyPostType
    etc.
```

I want it to be `MyPostType > All MyPostTypes`.
Hope somebody can help. I'd appreciate it! thanks

`//EDIT`
Trying to rephrase here (seems like people don't get my question, sorry for my lacking language skills)

1. I'm talking about the left hand menu in the **admin area**
2. I'm not looking for a plugin to make changes to that menu, I'm looking for code
3. of course I'm trying with `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page` but I can't get them to do what i want.

here it is again:
Using `add_menu_page('MyPostType',...)` and `add_submenu_page('Options',...)` gets me a top level menu entry called `MyPostType` with **two** submenu entries called `MyPostType` and `Options`. If you look at e.g. the `Posts` top level menu entry, they somehow managed to rename `Posts`(Submenu) to `All Posts`. That's what I want:

```
MyPostType
    All MyPostTypes
    Options
```

hope someone knows how to do that. thanks!

Comment: may be you could check http://generatewp.com/nav-menus/. Excellent wizard to do different stuff with wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the add_menu_page() method and add_submenu_page() method.

What does your code look like at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out by myself. her's how you'd do it.

use `add_menu_page` to create the top level menu entry. give it a slug to identify it.
use `add_submenu_page` to override the submenu entry created by `add_menu_page`. to override just give it the parents slug as the `parent` parameter. give it that exact same slug as the `menu_slug` parameter. that does the trick. now add as many more submenus as you want.